# Fatal error [0]: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given

Tags: php

I don't why I am getting this. I use this code to show album cover. Most of the albums/sub albums are working fine. But there are 2 of them that would throw error:
Fatal error [0]: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given

Any pointers will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

```
   .
// Get album cover
    if ($this->type == 'albums' and $this->output) {
        $coverTpl = '(SELECT *
        FROM %tImages%
        LEFT JOIN %tStorages% ON %tImages%.image_storage_id = %tStorages%.storage_id
        WHERE image_id = (SELECT album_cover_id FROM %tAlbums% WHERE album_id = %ALBUM_ID%)
        AND %tImages%.image_is_approved = 1
        LIMIT 1)';
        $album_cover_qry_tpl = strtr($coverTpl, [
            '%tImages%' => $tables['images'],
            '%tStorages%' => $tables['storages'],
            '%tAlbums%' => $tables['albums'],
        ]);
        $albums_cover_qry_arr = [];
        $albums_mapping = [];
        foreach ($this->output as $k => &$album) {
            if ($album['album_image_count'] < 0) {
                $album['album_image_count'] = 0;
            }
            $album['album_image_count_label'] = _n('image', 'images', $album['album_image_count']);
            $albums_cover_qry_arr[] = str_replace('%ALBUM_ID%', $album['album_id'], $album_cover_qry_tpl);
            $albums_mapping[$album['album_id']] = $k;
        }
        $albums_slice_qry = implode("\n" . 'UNION ALL ' . "\n", $albums_cover_qry_arr);
        $db->query($albums_slice_qry);
        $albums_slice = $db->fetchAll();
        if ($albums_slice) {
            foreach ($albums_slice as $slice) {
                $album_key = $albums_mapping[$slice['image_album_id']];
                if (!array_key_exists('album_images_slice', $this->output[$album_key])) {
                    $this->output[$album_key]['album_images_slice'] = [];
                }
                $this->output[$album_key]['album_images_slice'][] = $slice;
            }
        }
    }
}
.
.
```

Here is the var dump as requested:

```
array(2) { [0]=> &array(56) { ["album_id"]=> string(5) "11" ["album_name"]=> string(7) "2021-01" ["album_user_id"]=> string(5) "1" ["album_date"]=> string(19) "2021-02-16 14:27:07" ["album_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2021-02-16 06:27:07" ["album_creation_ip"]=> string(38) "redacted" ["album_privacy"]=> string(7) "private" ["album_privacy_extra"]=> NULL ["album_password"]=> NULL ["album_image_count"]=> string(1) "7" ["album_description"]=> NULL ["album_likes"]=> string(1) "0" ["album_views"]=> string(2) "11" ["album_cover_id"]=> string(7) "1292169" ["album_parent_id"]=> string(5) "19408" ["user_id"]=> string(5) "21192" ["user_name"]=> string(8) "redacted" ["user_username"]=> string(8) "redacted" ["user_date"]=> string(19) "2021-02-07 12:54:45" ["user_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2021-02-07 07:24:45" ["user_email"]=> string(20) "redacted" ["user_avatar_filename"]=> string(17) "av_1612654205.jpg" ["user_facebook_username"]=> NULL ["user_twitter_username"]=> NULL ["user_website"]=> string(0) "" ["user_background_filename"]=> NULL ["user_bio"]=> string(0) "" ["user_timezone"]=> string(17) "redacted" ["user_language"]=> string(2) "en" ["user_status"]=> string(5) "valid" ["user_is_admin"]=> string(1) "0" ["user_is_private"]=> string(1) "1" ["user_newsletter_subscribe"]=> string(1) "0" ["user_show_nsfw_listings"]=> string(1) "1" ["user_image_count"]=> string(2) "48" ["user_album_count"]=> string(2) "15" ["user_image_keep_exif"]=> string(1) "1" ["user_image_expiration"]=> NULL ["user_registration_ip"]=> string(37) "redacted" ["user_likes"]=> string(1) "0" ["user_liked"]=> string(1) "0" ["user_following"]=> string(1) "0" ["user_followers"]=> string(1) "0" ["user_content_views"]=> string(3) "170" ["user_notifications_unread"]=> string(1) "0" ["user_is_manager"]=> string(1) "0" ["user_is_dark_mode"]=> string(1) "1" ["like_id"]=> NULL ["like_date"]=> NULL ["like_date_gmt"]=> NULL ["like_user_id"]=> NULL ["like_content_type"]=> NULL ["like_content_id"]=> NULL ["like_content_user_id"]=> NULL ["like_ip"]=> NULL ["album_image_count_label"]=> string(6) "images" } [""]=> array(0) { } } NULL
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the statement `var_dump($this->output, $album_key);` before the `array_key_exists()` and add the debug output you get when you run your PHP script again.

Comment: @Progman added var dump as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't know why your variable is not an array. Acyually error message describes it quite well, for some reason some of `$this->output[$album_key]` are just `null`. You need to debug it yourself and fix it if required, as we have no access to your data.

However safest way to get rid such errors is usually checking if variable is array before you'll try to get or modify its data:

```php
if (is_array($this->output[$album_key]) && !array_key_exists('album_images_slice', $this->output[$album_key])) {
    $this->output[$album_key]['album_images_slice'] = [];
}
```

or even better, adding an empty array if doesn't exist:

```php
if(!is_array($this->output[$album_key])){
    $this->output[$album_key] = [];
}

if (!array_key_exists('album_images_slice', $this->output[$album_key])) {
    $this->output[$album_key]['album_images_slice'] = [];
}
```

Comment: This was really helpful. I found out that when sub-albums had cover image as null, error would trigger.
Thank you @biesior
It is not a solution, but it was helpful. I marking it as solved.